# Remember-me token: login event fired multiple times in the same second

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Laravel provides out-of-the-box events for authentication, so I'm using the `LoginListener` to log user logins in the database.

```
public function handle(Login $event) {

    if (!isset($event->user) || empty($event->user) ||
        !isset($event->user->userid) || empty($event->user->userid)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Auth::viaRemember())
        Logins::create(array('userid' => $event->user->userid, 'type' => 3));
    }

}
```

So, every time a user is being authenticated via the remember-me token, an entry is inserted in the `logins` table (user_id, type).

Problem is, sometimes I get multiple inserts for the same login event - sometimes even 20 rows, all with the same `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `user_id` and `type`. So, it seems the login event is fired multiple times and the listener, well, handles it multiple times, in the same single second

**Why might this be happening?**

Some background:

- The site architecture involves multiple hosts and load balancers.
- I'm using MySQL, with the `read` and `write` connections separated
- Laravel version: 5.4
- The multiple entries have been happening occasionally, in the span of
  the last few months
- The problem occurs on production and the development environment
- The event handler is not queued

Comment: I suggest to break inside `SessionGuard::fireLoginEvent()` to see how many times it's firing. Or is this only occurring in production? Is the event handler queued or anything like that?

Comment: No queuing, and the problem occurs on production and the development environment. I updated my post. I will take a look at the `fireLoginEvent()`, though.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was ?